# Return in try catch statement in java

Tags: java, return, try-catch, finally

In this method, where can I use return statement? Inside finally? or try ?

I am bit confused to return the string inside try catch statements.

Here is my code.

```
   public List<String> getEmailAddr(String strAccountnbr, String strCode) throws Exception {

        String strQuery2 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

     try

     {
        List<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();
        strQuery2 =  "SELECT c.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress" +

            " FROM customeremailid c " +
            "WHERE c.AccountNbr = ? " +
            "AND c.Code = ? ";

          logMsg("strQuery2: "+strQuery2);

          ps = getDBConn().prepareStatement(strQuery2);
          ps.setString(1, strAccountnbr);   
          ps.setString(2, strCode); 
          rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {   
            emailAddress.add((rs.getString("EmailAddress")));   
        } 


     }

     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }  

     return emailAddress;
     }
```

I am getting error as `emailAddress cannot resolved to a variable.`
Any help?

Comment: Not inside a `finally` block, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting error as `emailAddress` cannot resolved to a variable. Any
>   help?

```
List<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();//Declare it outside the block
try{...
```

*OR* Declare outside but initialize inside `try` to make it accessible in `catch` block.

```
List<String> emailAddress=null;
try{...
emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();//Initialize it inside the block
```

*Right now* your `emailAddress` is only accessible in `try{//Block}` but not in `catch{//Block}`

Comment: I declared outside the block. Whether will I get exception in catch, if there is no emailaddress?

Comment: @user3152748 you will get Nullpointer but if you get any exception you can return null or specific error message in catch block.It's your bet!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<String> getEmailAddr(String strAccountnbr, String strCode) throws Exception {

        String strQuery2 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        List<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();

     try{

         strQuery2 =  "SELECT c.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress" +
                      " FROM customeremailid c " +
                      " WHERE c.AccountNbr = ? " +
                      " AND c.Code = ? ";

          logMsg("strQuery2: "+strQuery2);
          ps = getDBConn().prepareStatement(strQuery2);
          ps.setString(1, strAccountnbr);   
          ps.setString(2, strCode); 
          rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {   
            emailAddress.add((rs.getString("EmailAddress")));   
        } 


     }

     catch(Exception e)
     {
         //some error especify your exception or uses a generic..
         throw new EmailAdressException("BLA BLA BLA...")
     }  
     //if everything is fine return  email
     return emailAddress;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
List<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();
try
{
....
}

return emailAddress;
```

Previously, the variable that your were trying to return was limited to the try block scope.

Answer (score 0):

`return` can be used inside `try` block or outside `try - catch` block, `finally` block is basically for relinquishing resources not for writing return statements.

Comment: No, this is not true. You can limit this try-catch to only handle possible query exceptions, and then handle the rest of the code (including return statements) outside try/catch.

Comment: @Handsomeguy If I got you correctly, you mean to say there is no need to write `finally` block?

Comment: No, what is not true is "Return must always be used inside try block"

Comment: @Handsomeguy removed ambiguous part, as there was also another line "or can be used outside `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider scope. In your code, as you declare your emailAddress inside a block (the try-block), emailAddress is only available inside that block. The try-catch is here only useful for handling possible exceptions when executing the query. Try to limit try-catch to only the code that will throw an exception (in this case you could/should refactor your code so that the query is done in its own method).

If you declare emailAddress outside the try-catch block, you return it after the catch block.

```
public List<String> getEmailAddr(String strAccountnbr, String strCode) throws Exception {
    List<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();

     try {
         // Handle query here
     } catch(Exception e) {
         // You should not catch Exception, but a more fine-grained exception.
         // In this case, SQLException
     } 

     return emailAddress;
 }
```